# Thingsboard process data from device and reinject it as new telemetry data

Tags: cassandra, thingsboard

I'm working on an IoT project that involves a sensor transmitting its values to an IoT platform. One of the platforms that I'm currently testing is Thingsboard, it is Open Source and I find it quite easy to manage.

My sensor is transmitting active energy indexes to Thingsboard. Using these values, I would like to calculate and show on a widget the values of the active power (= k*[ActiveEnergy(n)- ActiveEnergy(n-1)/Time(n)-Time(n-1)]). This basically means that I want to have access to history data, use this data to generate new data and inject it to my device.

Thingsboard uses Cassandra database to save history values. 
One alternative to my problem could be to find a way to communicate with the database via a Web API for example, do the processing and send back the active power by MQTT or HTTP on my device using its access token.
Is this possible?
Is there a better alternative to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options how to achieve this (based on a layer or component of the system):

1) Visualization layer only. Probably the most simple one. There is an option to apply **post-processing function**. The function has following signature:

function(time, value, prevValue)

Please note that prevTime is missing, but we may add this in future releases.

[post processing function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuEYz.png)

2) Data processing layer. Use advanced analytics frameworks like Apache Spark to post-process your data using sliding time window, for example.
See our [**integration article**](https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/analytics/spark-integration-with-thingsboard/) about this.

Comment: Hi Yana! For the first option, you are talking about the visualization layer but how to access the menu shown on the picture joined?

Comment: Hi Ghita! On any widget, go to edit mode, open "Data" tab, locate your data source and click on "pencil" icon near telemetry or attribute key. Now you will see "Data key configuration" window. Click on "Use data-processing function" and you will see the screen.

Comment: Okey, found the menu, thank you. Now, when I use the post-processing function, I notice that the prevValue is always equal to 0 which is not true in my case. Do I have to do something so that the prevValue is correctly updated?

Comment: Are you reporting telemetry value as a string, double or long?

Comment: The json I'm sending to Thingsboard is as the following: {'Channel1': 3127.34567786532}. So I guess I'm reporting the telemetry value as a double. When received on the platform, it becomes a telemetry value that I use to be shown on a Flot Bar Graph; which is correctly displayed. Now when I use the post processing function and I display typeof(value) it returns the type String...

Comment: I understand, this is probably a bug. Please open an issue on [github](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues).

Comment: It's not a bug, but rather an unimplemented feature, at least according to Yana's message above: "Please note that prevTime is missing, but we may add this in future releases."